# if user input is not a directory, how can I make the directory a default value

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

Let us say a user input is an invalid directory. if so how can I make a script automatically set a default directory to a local file or the desktop?

Comment: I would try a simple `if` statement in combination with `os.path.isdir(path)`.

Comment: You can use  `chdir` command of the `os` module like this 
```
import os 
os.chdir(r"C:\DirectoryOfYourChoice")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `os` library and check if a directory exists:

```
isFile = os.path.isdir(path)
```

if `isFile` is false then set it to whatever default directory you want. If you want it to be set to Desktop, then use:

```
os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\Desktop'
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
os.path.exists(path)
```

to see if it exists. If it does not, you can set set another `path`.
If you want to change directory, you can use

```
os.chdir(path)
```